# More efficient way of splitting columns on text and converting column to binary category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of comma separated categories in object format.  There are 40 or so different majors represented in the column. 
In my example below I'm saving space by only demonstrating a few.

```py
    Visit_Age   Sex    Majors                           Visit_Count   CEEB
0   18.469921   F      Literature, Visual Arts          1.0           030517
1   17.487012   F      Biology, Ceramics, Dance, Vis... 1.0           333685
2   17.853892   F      Architecture, Drawing, Vis...    2.0           390105
3   17.579160   M      Psychology                       0.0           050162
4   17.579160   F      Literature, Writing              0.0           333705
```

Currently I'm just manually creating the new columns like this.  Kind of like a OneHotEncode(), but I couldn't get that to work with a str.split().  And it seems silly to have to break this out into so many lines of code.

```
cleanedData['Major_Lit'] = np.where(cleanedData['Majors'].str.contains('Literature') == True, 1, 0)
cleanedData['Major_VA'] = np.where(cleanedData['Majors'].str.contains('Visual Arts') == True, 1, 0)
cleanedData['Major_Bio'] = np.where(cleanedData['Majors'].str.contains('Biology') == True, 1, 0)
cleanedData['Major_Arch'] = np.where(cleanedData['Majors'].str.contains('Architecture') == True, 1, 0)
cleanedData['Major_Draw'] = np.where(cleanedData['Majors'].str.contains('Drawing') == True, 1, 0)
```

I'm then converting the columns into categories, I managed to optimize this partly, though I suspect it could be better.

```
for column in cleanedData[['Major_Lit', 'Major_VA', 'Major_Bio', 'Major_Arch', 'Major_Draw']]:
   retypetype = cleanedData[column]
   cleanedData[column] = cleanedData[column].astype('category')
```

What I'm looking for help on is doing this all in a more efficient way. 
Split column into distinct majors, and append to other existing columns as a category dtype.

Comment: Check `np.select` as an alternative to all those `np.where`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's the best, but `str.get_dummies()` sure is a good choice:

```
df.Majors.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

Output:

```
    Ceramics   Dance   Drawing   Visual Arts   Writing  Architecture  Biology  ...
0          0       0         0             1         0             0        0   
1          1       1         0             1         0             0        1   
2          0       0         1             1         0             1        0   
3          0       0         0             0         0             0        0   
4          0       0         0             0         1             0        0
```

Comment: This worked, and I added `.astype('category')` to the end

Comment: It's very concise, great, but the spaces must be cut off from the column strings.